# Shortest Reach Graph on HackerRank

Tags: algorithm, graph

I have submitted a solution for this (https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/ctci-bfs-shortest-reach) problem on HackerRank. It fails for certain test cases. I have not been able to figure out what is incorrect in my solution.

**Problem Statement**

Consider an undirected graph consisting of  *n* nodes where each node is labeled from *1* to *n* and the edge between any two nodes is always of length *6*. We define node *s*  to be the starting position for a BFS.

Given *q* queries in the form of a graph and some starting node, *s* , perform each query by calculating the shortest distance from starting node  *s* to all the other nodes in the graph. Then print a single line of  space-separated integers listing node *s* 's shortest distance to each of the  other nodes (ordered sequentially by node number); if *s* is disconnected from a node, print  as the distance to that node.

**Input Format**

The first line contains an integer, *q* , denoting the number of queries. The subsequent lines describe each query in the following format:

The first line contains two space-separated integers describing the respective values of *n* (the number of nodes) and *m* (the number of edges) in the graph.
Each line *i* of the *m* subsequent lines contains two space-separated integers, *u* and *v*, describing an edge connecting node *u* to node *v*.
The last line contains a single integer, *s*, denoting the index of the starting node.

Output Format

For each of the *q* queries, print a single line of *n-1* space-separated integers denoting the shortest distances to each of the  other nodes from starting position *s*. These distances should be listed sequentially by node number (i.e., *1,2...n*), but should not include node s. If some node is unreachable from *s*, print  *-1* as the distance to that node.

**Example**

Sample Input:

```
    2
    4 2
    1 2
    1 3
    1
    3 1
    2 3
    2
```

Sample Output:

```
6 6 -1
-1 6
```

My solution:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

    public static class Graph {
        //key = node. value = list of neighbors.
       Map<Integer, List<Integer>> nodes;

        public Graph(int size) {
            nodes = new HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>>();
            for(int i = 0; i<size; i++){
                nodes.put(i, new ArrayList<Integer>());
            }
        }

        public void addEdge(int first, int second) {
            if(first != second){
               if(!(nodes.get(first).contains(second))){
                    nodes.get(first).add(second);
                }
                if(!(nodes.get(second).contains(first))){
                    nodes.get(second).add(first);
                } 
            }
        }

        public int[] shortestReach(int startId) { // 0 indexed
            int[] distances = new int[nodes.keySet().size()];
            Arrays.fill(distances, -1);
            distances[startId] = 0;
            visitNeighbors(startId, distances);
            return distances;
        }

        private void visitNeighbors(int startId, int[] distances){
            List<Integer> nodesToVisit = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for(int i:nodes.get(startId)){
                if(distances[i] == -1){
                    distances[i] = distances[startId] + 6;
                    nodesToVisit.add(i);
                }
                //dont recurse right here, otherwise it will become depth-first and we will not get shortest path.
            }
            for(int i:nodesToVisit){
                visitNeighbors(i, distances);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        int queries = scanner.nextInt();

        for (int t = 0; t < queries; t++) {

            // Create a graph of size n where each edge weight is 6:
            Graph graph = new Graph(scanner.nextInt());
            int m = scanner.nextInt();

            // read and set edges
            for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
                int u = scanner.nextInt() - 1;
                int v = scanner.nextInt() - 1;

                // add each edge to the graph
                graph.addEdge(u, v);
            }

            // Find shortest reach from node s
            int startId = scanner.nextInt() - 1;
            int[] distances = graph.shortestReach(startId);

            for (int i = 0; i < distances.length; i++) {
                if (i != startId) {
                    System.out.print(distances[i]);
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();            
        }

        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

When I submit the above code, HackerRank reports that certain TestCases did not pass. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a pretty straight forward bfs problem.

Your `visit` method is not correct, considering it's pointing to `visitNeighbors`.

Make it a bfs function. currently, it's a recursive method making it a `stack` instead of a `queue`.

```
    private void visitNeighbors(int startId, int[] distances){
        List<Integer> nodesToVisit = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        nodesToVisit.add(startId);
        distances[startId] = 0;
        while (!nodesToVisit.isEmpty()) {
            int current = nodesToVisit.get(0);
            nodesToVisit.remove(0);
            for (int i : nodes.get(current)) {
                if (distances[i] == -1) {
                    distances[i] = distances[current] + 6;
                    nodesToVisit.add(i);
                }
                //dont recurse right here, otherwise it will become depth-first and we will not get shortest path.
            }
        }
    }
```

[Here](https://pastebin.com/tDAXg6yS) is the edited accepted code.

Comment: Thanks! I did not realize that by using recursion (in spite of my comment in code), I was doing depth first. That must have lead to some non-shortest paths. Thanks!